# Showing that a multivariable function is one to one

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am stuck with the following problem

I am given the function $f$ such that $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ I am supposed to show that the function is one to one.

For a function to be one to one, $f'>0$. If I differentiate this function, I get the matrix

$\begin{matrix} 2x&-2y\\2y&2x\end{matrix}$

How do I proceed from this step further?

Any hint would be appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ for $x,y>0$.

If $f(x,y)=f(a,b)$, then $x^2-y^2=a^2-b^2$ and $2xy=2ab$.

Then $x^2-a^2=y^2-b^2\implies (x-a)(x+a)=(y-b)(y+b)$ and $2xy=2ab\implies xy=ab$.

Assume that $x\ne a$; then without loss of generality, we can assume that $x>a$.

Then $xy=ab\implies y<b$, so $(x-a)(x+a)>0$ while $(y-b)(y+b)<0$; and this gives a contradiction.

Therefore $x=a$, and $xy=ab\implies y=b \implies (x,y)=(a,b)$.

Thus $f$ is 1-1.

Comment: This is a great answer. I thought of a new way, could you please say something about it? Is it acceptable to find the Jacobian of the given function and then conclude that since Jacobian is not equal to zero, then it is invertible. Since it is invertible, then it is one to one?

Comment: Thanks - I believe the Jacobian being nonzero shows that the function is locally invertible, but I don't think it guarantees that it is invertible.  (For example, as Yulia V has pointed out, the function is not invertible on $\{(x,y):x\ne 0$ or $y\ne 0}$ even though the Jacobian is nonzero on this set.)

Answer (score 2):

It is one-to-one on positive numbers, but not on integer numbers, since $f(x,y)=f(-x,-y)$.

If we assume that we have to show that it is one-to-one on positive numbers, we need to find how to invert this function. Note that
$(x^2-y^2)^2+(2xy)^2 = (x^2+y^2)^2$. Thus $$f^{-1}(u,v) = \left(\sqrt{0.5(\sqrt{u^2+v^2}+ u)}, \sqrt{0.5(\sqrt{u^2+v^2} - u)}\right)$$

Comment: Does it suffice to conclude that the function is one to one just to show that we can find the inverse of the function? @YuliaV

Comment: Yes, if it exists for all points or the space of values of $f$ and is unique. As I have shown, if you allow negative values of x and y, it won't be unique; in this case it won't be one-to-one.